# Can you please help me identify this insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I have been trying to get rid of this bug and need help to identify it.
I found this in my bedroom first.

I don't think this is a bed bug as I saw it fly. It is black with some white spots on it.

Any suggestions on what it could be are greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add where you found this insect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bean weevil, family Chrysomelidae, subfamily Bruchinae. If you have dried beans at home, check for an infestation. Throw out the contaminated beans, and put your others in sealed plastic containers, or in the fridge. https://bugguide.net/node/view/13857

Comment: Thanks Karl, I checked my beans one kind of them was indeed infested with them, no rice or other grains were infested. But I still have one question how come they spread that much? Because there is a huge no of those in my house

Comment: They must have found another food source, or were attracted by the original infestation.